# Magento 2: Add or edit address in popup

Tags: magento2, address, popup

In customer account address book, add or edit address is managed in separate page.

I want to **add or edit address in popup modal(same like shipping address popup modal in checkout page)***.

***How it can be done ?***

Answer (score 1):

You should read example from Magento_Checkout module files such as

- `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js:138`
- `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html:29`
- `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js:196`

These file will show your step by step add Popup address form, then save form data using Ajax.

Sample code.

**- html template file**

```
<button type="button"
                data-bind="click: showFormPopUp, visible: !isNewAddressAdded()"
                class="action action-show-popup">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'New Address'"></span></button>
        <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" data-bind="visible: isFormPopUpVisible()">
            <!-- ko template: 'Namespace_ModuleName/shipping-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
```

**- JS ui component file **

```
 define(
        [
            'jquery',
            'underscore',
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
            'ko'],
    function (
            $,
            _,
            Component,
            ko){
return Component.extend({
            /**
             * @return {*}
             */
            getPopUp: function () {
                var self = this,
                    buttons;

                if (!popUp) {
                    buttons = this.popUpForm.options.buttons;
                    this.popUpForm.options.buttons = [
                        {
                            text: buttons.save.text ? buttons.save.text : $t('Save Address'),
                            class: buttons.save.class ? buttons.save.class : 'action primary action-save-address',
                            click: self.saveNewAddress.bind(self)
                        },
                        {
                            text: buttons.cancel.text ? buttons.cancel.text : $t('Cancel'),
                            class: buttons.cancel.class ? buttons.cancel.class : 'action secondary action-hide-popup',

                            /** @inheritdoc */
                            click: this.onClosePopUp.bind(this)
                        }
                    ];
                    this.popUpForm.options.closed = function () {
                        self.isFormPopUpVisible(false);
                    };

                    this.popUpForm.options.modalCloseBtnHandler = this.onClosePopUp.bind(this);
                    this.popUpForm.options.keyEventHandlers = {
                        escapeKey: this.onClosePopUp.bind(this)
                    };

                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    this.popUpForm.options.opened = function () {
                        // Store temporary address for revert action in case when user click cancel action
                        self.temporaryAddress = $.extend(true, {}, checkoutData.getShippingAddressFromData());
                    };
                    popUp = modal(this.popUpForm.options, $(this.popUpForm.element));
                }

                return popUp;
            },

            /**
             * Revert address and close modal.
             */
            onClosePopUp: function () {
                checkoutData.setShippingAddressFromData($.extend(true, {}, this.temporaryAddress));
                this.getPopUp().closeModal();
            },

            /**
             * Show address form popup
             */
            showFormPopUp: function () {
                this.isFormPopUpVisible(true);
            },

            /**
             * Save new shipping address
             */
            saveNewAddress: function () {
                var addressData,
                    newShippingAddress;

                this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
                this.source.trigger('shippingAddress.data.validate');

                if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                    addressData = this.source.get('shippingAddress');
                    // if user clicked the checkbox, its value is true or false. Need to convert.
                    addressData.save_in_address_book = this.saveInAddressBook ? 1 : 0;
                    console.log(addressData);// This is address data fill by customer
                    this.getPopUp().closeModal();
                    this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
                }
            },
         });
    }
);
```

Comment: Where is the code to save address data ?

Comment: **console.log(addressData);// This is address data fill by customer** this line, you can post **addressData** to your ajax controller to save that.

Comment: how to populate the popup form with default address for logged in user?

Comment: Hi @LizEipeC you can add default data for the popup. or auto-fill data using javascript after popup opened.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you please advise how to get the stored address for auto filling the form? Which file I need to edit for making this change? Thanks in advance

Comment: U can be using layoutProcessors to modify checkout config data, add your custom data and you can use it on your UiComponent.